# Vue cli pages with scss prependData @import not importing to all pages

Tags: vue.js, electron, vue-cli

I am trying to load a default global theme into all of my electron windows, so I created the following `vue.config.js` file:

```js
module.exports = {
  pages: {
    index: 'src/windows/main/main.ts',
    newImage: {
      entry: 'src/windows/newImage/main.ts',
      template: 'public/newImage.html'
    }
  },
  css: {
    loaderOptions: {
      scss: {
        prependData: '@import "~@/sass/theme.scss";'
      }
    },
    requireModuleExtension: false
  }
}
```

This works when loading the initial window, but when I open a new modal window like this:

```js
let win = new BrowserWindow({ modal: true, parent, /* other settings */})
```

The `theme.scss` file doesn't load into the new BrowserWindow. Any ideas as to why this is happening?

Comment: I've got the same problem. Did you find a solution?

Comment: @Jan Nope, I was never able to figure it out sadly.